# There are no commands defined in the "indexer" namespace

Tags: php, magento2

I just installed `Magento 2` in my local.
And after getting installed, I am getting a warning

> One or more indexers are invalid. in my dashboard.

To fix this warning, I ran

```sh
sudo php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

But it is giving me an error

> [InvalidArgumentException]
> There are no commands defined in the "indexer" namespace.

Please anyone can help me install `Magento 2` and fix these issues.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Magento version 2.1.7 and php version 7.0

Comment: I think, this question looks helpful: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/95439/magento-2-how-to-solve-an-error-when-reindex-by-cli